# Representing a continuous time hedge discretely

Tags: options, greeks, delta-hedging

I recently came across an example ([Section 5.2.9 here](https://bookdown.org/maxime_debellefroid/MyBook/the-greeks.html)) which does a simple delta hedging experiment. Below are the details:

---

**Market conditions**

Interest rates are at a 2% level --> r = 0.02

The underlying stock pays no dividend and follows a Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM) with µ = 10% and σ = 20%

The initial spot price is 100€ --> S0 = 100

The call option is ATM with a maturity of 0.1 years --> T = 0.1

We are going to delta hedge at regular time step with dt = 0.005 so that there are 20 steps. We will generate sample paths of the stocks by generating standard normal deviates and using the known formula. From the time series, we can calculate back the realized volatility after the experiment --> realized volatility = 17%.

**First Day**

The trader sells the option at a price of 2.62€, corresponding to an implied volatility of 20%. He will also use this implied volatility for hedging purposes, which prescribed a delta of 52.52% so that he buys 0.5252 stocks. He does this by borrowing (0.5252 ∗ 100€ − 2.62€) = 49.90€.

After the first day, the trader has the following instruments in his book:

A sold call option at 2.62€

A loan with a present value of 49.90€

A stock portfolio with a value of 52.52€

**Second Day**

The outstanding loan is increased because of the interest effect. In this case, the effect is about 1 cent. The stock has decreased by 10 cents. Because of the delta of his position, his stock portfolio loses about 5 cents. The sold option loses more than just 5 cents.

All of this brings the trader's book to a positive value. The theory of Black-Scholes is prescribing that the hedging cost leads to the option price. However, we notice a profit coming into the book after just one day of hedging! Why?

The reason is that the theory assumes that you are hedging continuously through time, rather than once a day. So the error is induced by the discrete nature of the hedging strategy.

Another way of looking at this is by analyzing the random number that was used to generate the value of the second day. This number is a draw from the standard normal distribution. This one is a small number.

One could say that the volatility of the first day, because of this small draw, is smaller than actually predicted by the distribution. It is smaller than the "typical" number in a standard normal distribution.

Which random number one has to use in order to see no profit and no loss on this first day?

Z = -1 or +1 --> one standard deviation out of the mean."

---

My question is how is the book value positive? The loan which is a liability increased by a cent. The short call is fixed and was used to purchase the portfolio while the portfolio itself is down by 5 cents. Doesn't this add up to a net negative value? Also, how was Z = 1 derived for a net zero position?

Comment: This example is not complete because he never mentions BY HOW MUCH THE STOCK MOVED ON THE SECOND DAY. Which is key to the whole thing, without it you cannot calculate the P&L and see if it is positive. Later he mentions the move was small, but nowhere does he give the amount. I believe without referring to the complete example with all the numbers you cannot see the point he is trying to make: that with discrete hedging the SIZE OF THE MOVE (larger or smaller than 1 std dev) determines the P&L.

Comment: Also, the short call shouldn't be on the book after the first day right? It is the premium earned plus the debt used to purchase the stock so it should be removed after the transaction. Dunno why he makes this statement when that transaction is already done: 'The sold option loses more than just 5 cents.'

Comment: No, you are short an option and it has to be marked to market each day to find the P&L.

Comment: Aah yes because it's the obligation. Thanks

Comment: The author says he adapted this example from the book 'The Greeks and Hedging Explained' by Peter Leoni (which I don't have). My impression is it is a poor adaptation, badly explained, it is not worth spending much time with this post.